# Oracle Spatial - SDO_GEOM.RELATE Inconsistencies

Tags: oracle-spatial, tolerance

I'm using Oracle 12.2 (12c) and encountering some inconsistent results with the `SDO_GEOM.RELATE` function.

When I run the following code to check if two points are equal on the projected Irish grid, taking into account a tolerance, as expected I get a result of "EQUAL":

```
  SDO_GEOM.RELATE
  (
    MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,29902,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(325511.001,313661.001,NULL),NULL,NULL),
    'EQUAL',
    MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,29902,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(325511,313661,NULL),NULL,NULL),
    0.001
  )
```

But when I adjust to use a larger tolerance and a larger distance between points, I get a result of "FALSE":

```
  SDO_GEOM.RELATE
  (
    MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,29902,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(325511.01,313661.01,NULL),NULL,NULL),
    'EQUAL',
    MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,29902,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(325511,313661,NULL),NULL,NULL),
    0.01
  )
```

Here's a breakdown of my results for a given tolerance/distance:

```
0.0001 - FALSE
0.001 - EQUAL
0.01 - FALSE
0.1 - FALSE
1 - EQUAL
```

What is going on here?

Comment: This is likely just an IEEE floating-point equivalence comparison issue. What happens when you use values that are clearly outside and  inside, instead of on the line?

Comment: I agree, adjust tolerances into 0.00015, 0.0015, 0.015, and 0.15 or edit the point coordinates a bit.

Comment: Thanks guys. It does appear to be a floating point issue, as adjusting the coords to bring them further inside the tolerance causes them all to return "EQUAL". Adding the trailing 5 also fixes it.

Comment: Please write that as an answer. You may also edit the title to better describe what you found like "Oracle and inconsistent equality of coordinates with tolerance".